# I am trying to add an new item but I get an empty item in my table

Tags: sapui5

When I add an new item by using add icon on my page everything happens in true way. But when I try to add an new item by useng (insert) from kyeboard , then write the new item info and click on add button on dialog view, I get new item but without information, just new row with empty cells. can somene help me please?

```css
////sap.ui.define is a function used for module definition. It allows to define dependencies and 
//specify the callback function that will be executed when all dependencies are loaded.
sap.ui.define([
    
            
            var table = this.byId("table");
            table.addEventDelegate({
                onkeydown: function(oEvent) {
                    if (oEvent.keyCode === 46) {
                        this.onRemoveRowsUi();
                    }
                    /*  if (oEvent.keyCode === 45) {
                            this.onCreate();
                        }*/
                }.bind(this)
            });
            var view = this.getView();
            view.addEventDelegate({
                onkeydown: function(oEvent) {
                    if (oEvent.keyCode === 45) { // Check if Insert key is pressed
                        this.onOpenDialog(); // Call the onOpenDialog function to open the dialog
                    }
                }.bind(this)
            });

        },
        onOpenDialog: function() {
            var dialog = this.getView().byId("oDialogCreate");
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            dialog.open();
        },

        selectAll: function(oEvent) {
            var otab = this.byId("table"); // Fetch the table

            var bSelected = oEvent.getParameter('selected'); // fetch whether user selected/de-selected all

            otab.getItems().forEach(function(item) { // loop over all the items in the table
                var oCheckBoxCell = item.getCells()[0]; //fetch the cell which holds the checkbox for that row.

                oCheckBoxCell.setSelected(bSelected); // Select/de-select each checkbox
            });
        },

        ............code .....
        onCreate: function() {

            this.getView().byId("oDialogCreate").setVisible(true).open(); //Refers to the current view object. is used to retrieve the current view instance.This makes the control visible on the screen.
        },

        onAdd: function() {
            // Get the input field values
            var name = this.byId("nameInput").getValue();
            var category = this.byId("categoryInput").getValue();
            var supplier = this.byId("supplierInput").getValue();
            var status = this.byId("statusInput").getValue();
            var dateOfProduction = this.byId("dateOfProductionInput").getValue();
            var price = this.byId("priceInput").getValue();

            // Create a new item object with the entered values
            var newItem = {
                Name: name,
                Category: category,
                SupplierName: supplier,
                Status: status,
                DateOfProduction: dateOfProduction,
                Price: price
            };

            // Get the table model and add the new item to it
            var oTable = this.byId("table");
            var oModel = oTable.getModel();
            var aItems = oModel.getProperty("/ProductCollection");
            aItems.push(newItem);
            oModel.setProperty("/ProductCollection", aItems);

            // Close the dialog
            this.byId("oDialogCreate").close();
        },

        onCancel: function() {
            this.getView().byId("oDialogCreate").setVisible(true).close();
        },
        checkDone: function(oEvent) {
            var bSelected = oEvent.getParameter('selected');
            var oItem = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject();

            if (bSelected) {
                this.selectedItems.push(oItem);
            } else {
                var index = this.selectedItems.indexOf(oItem);
                if (index !== -1) {
                    this.selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        },

        code..........
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<mvc:View controllerName="com.volkswagen.ifdb.cc.sopraempApplication.controller.Overview" height="100%" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.f" xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar" xmlns:svm="sap.ui.comp.smartvariants"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:smartTable="sap.ui.comp.smarttable" xmlns:smartFilterBar="sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar">
    
    <App id="app">
        <f:DynamicPage id="page" headerExpanded="{/headerExpanded}">
            <f:title>
                <f:DynamicPageTitle>
                    <f:heading>
                        <svm:SmartVariantManagement id="svm" showExecuteOnSelection="true"/>
                    </f:heading>
                    <f:expandedContent>
                        <Label id="expandedLabel" text="No filters active"/>
                    </f:expandedContent>
                    <f:snappedContent>
                        <Label id="snappedLabel" text="No filters active"/>
                    </f:snappedContent>
                </f:DynamicPageTitle>
            </f:title>
            <f:header>
                <f:DynamicPageHeader>
                    <f:content>
                        <fb:FilterBar id="filterbar" persistencyKey="myPersKey" useToolbar="false" search=".onSearch" filterChange=".onFilterChange"
                            afterVariantLoad=".onAfterVariantLoad">
                            <fb:filterGroupItems>
                                <fb:FilterGroupItem name="Name" label="Name" groupName="Group1" visibleInFilterBar="true">
                                    <fb:control>
                                        <MultiComboBox name="Name" selectionChange=".onSelectionChange" items="{ path: '/ProductNames', templateShareable: true }">
                                            <core:Item key="{key}" text="{name}"/>
                                        </MultiComboBox>
                                    </fb:control>
                                </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                                <fb:FilterGroupItem name="Category" label="Category" groupName="Group1" visibleInFilterBar="true">
                                    <fb:control>
                                        <MultiComboBox name="Category" selectionChange=".onSelectionChange" items="{ path: '/ProductCategories', templateShareable: true }">
                                            <core:Item key="{key}" text="{name}"/>
                                        </MultiComboBox>
                                    </fb:control>
                                </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                                <fb:FilterGroupItem name="SupplierName" label="SupplierName" groupName="Group1" visibleInFilterBar="true">
                                    <fb:control>
                                        <MultiComboBox name="SupplierName" selectionChange=".onSelectionChange" items="{ path: '/ProductSuppliers', templateShareable: true }">
                                            <core:Item key="{key}" text="{name}"/>
                                        </MultiComboBox>
                                    </fb:control>
                                </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                            </fb:filterGroupItems>
                        </fb:FilterBar>
                    </f:content>
                </f:DynamicPageHeader>
            </f:header>
            <f:content>
                <Table id="table" inset="false" items="{path: '/ProductCollection'}" itemPress="onPress" >
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <ToolbarSpacer/>
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://add" press="onCreate"/>
                            <!--    <Button icon="sap-icon://edit" press="onEdit"/>-->
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://delete" press="onRemoveRowsUi"/>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <columns>
                        <Column width="5em">
                            <CheckBox select="selectAll"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column >
                            <Text text="Name"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Category"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="SupplierName"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Status"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="DateOfProduction"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Price"/>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items >
                        <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle" type="Navigation">
                            <cells >
                                <CheckBox id="ch1" select="checkDone"/>
                                <!--    <RadioButton id="selected" text="" selected="true"/>-->
                                <ObjectIdentifier title="{Name}" text="{ProductId}"/>
                                <Text text="{Category}"/>
                                <Text text="{SupplierName}"/>
                                <ObjectIdentifier title="{Status}" text="{Quantity}"/>
                                <Text text="{DateOfProduction}"/>
                                <ObjectNumber number="{Price}" unit="{CurrencyCode}"/>
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>


                </Table>
            </f:content>
        </f:DynamicPage>
        <!--resizable="true" resize Dialog
            draggable="true" is default, dragg Dilaog
            -->


    <Dialog id="oDialogCreate" title="Create New Item" contentWidth="400px" resizable="true" class="myDialogStyle" >
    <content>
        <VBox alignItems="Center">
            <Label text="Name" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="nameInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput" />
            <Label text="Category" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="categoryInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput"/>
            <Label text="Supplier" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="supplierInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput"/>
            <Label text="Status" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="statusInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput"/>
            <Label text="DateOfProductionInput" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="dateOfProductionInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput"/>
            <Label text="Price" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="priceInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput"/>
        </VBox>
    </content>
    <beginButton>
        <Button text="Add" type="Accept" press="onAdd" class="dialogButton"/>
    </beginButton>
    <endButton>
        <Button text="Cancel" type="Reject" press="onCancel" class="dialogButton"/>
    </endButton>
</Dialog>

    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

```css
////sap.ui.define is a function used for module definition. It allows to define dependencies and 
//specify the callback function that will be executed when all dependencies are loaded.
sap.ui.define([
    

        onInit: function() {

        ........code......
        

            

            var table = this.byId("table");
            table.addEventDelegate({
                onkeydown: function(oEvent) {
                    if (oEvent.keyCode === 46) {
                        this.onRemoveRowsUi();
                    }
                    /*  if (oEvent.keyCode === 45) {
                            this.onCreate();
                        }*/
                }.bind(this)
            });
            var view = this.getView();
            view.addEventDelegate({
                onkeydown: function(oEvent) {
                    if (oEvent.keyCode === 45) { // Check if Insert key is pressed
                        this.onOpenDialog(); // Call the onOpenDialog function to open the dialog
                    }
                }.bind(this)
            });

        },
        onOpenDialog: function() {
            var dialog = this.getView().byId("oDialogCreate");
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            dialog.open();
        },

        selectAll: function(oEvent) {
            var otab = this.byId("table"); // Fetch the table

            var bSelected = oEvent.getParameter('selected'); // fetch whether user selected/de-selected all

            otab.getItems().forEach(function(item) { // loop over all the items in the table
                var oCheckBoxCell = item.getCells()[0]; //fetch the cell which holds the checkbox for that row.

                oCheckBoxCell.setSelected(bSelected); // Select/de-select each checkbox
            });
        },

            ........code......

        onCreate: function() {

            this.getView().byId("oDialogCreate").setVisible(true).open(); //Refers to the current view object. is used to retrieve the current view instance.This makes the control visible on the screen.
        },

        onAdd: function() {
            // Get the input field values
            var name = this.byId("nameInput").getValue();
            var category = this.byId("categoryInput").getValue();
            var supplier = this.byId("supplierInput").getValue();
            var status = this.byId("statusInput").getValue();
            var dateOfProduction = this.byId("dateOfProductionInput").getValue();
            var price = this.byId("priceInput").getValue();

            // Create a new item object with the entered values
            var newItem = {
                Name: name,
                Category: category,
                SupplierName: supplier,
                Status: status,
                DateOfProduction: dateOfProduction,
                Price: price
            };

            // Get the table model and add the new item to it
            var oTable = this.byId("table");
            var oModel = oTable.getModel();
            var aItems = oModel.getProperty("/ProductCollection");
            aItems.push(newItem);
            oModel.setProperty("/ProductCollection", aItems);

            // Close the dialog
            this.byId("oDialogCreate").close();
        },

        onCancel: function() {
            this.getView().byId("oDialogCreate").setVisible(true).close();
        },
        checkDone: function(oEvent) {
            var bSelected = oEvent.getParameter('selected');
            var oItem = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject();

            if (bSelected) {
                this.selectedItems.push(oItem);
            } else {
                var index = this.selectedItems.indexOf(oItem);
                if (index !== -1) {
                    this.selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        },

            ........code......
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<mvc:View controllerName="com.volkswagen.ifdb.cc.sopraempApplication.controller.Overview" height="100%" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.f" xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar" xmlns:svm="sap.ui.comp.smartvariants"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:smartTable="sap.ui.comp.smarttable" xmlns:smartFilterBar="sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar">
    
    <App id="app">
        <f:DynamicPage id="page" headerExpanded="{/headerExpanded}">
            <f:title>

            ........code......
        
                    <items >
                        <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle" type="Navigation">
                            <cells >
                                <CheckBox id="ch1" select="checkDone"/>
                                <!--    <RadioButton id="selected" text="" selected="true"/>-->
                                <ObjectIdentifier title="{Name}" text="{ProductId}"/>
                                <Text text="{Category}"/>
                                <Text text="{SupplierName}"/>
                                <ObjectIdentifier title="{Status}" text="{Quantity}"/>
                                <Text text="{DateOfProduction}"/>
                                <ObjectNumber number="{Price}" unit="{CurrencyCode}"/>
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>


                </Table>
            </f:content>
        </f:DynamicPage>
        <!--resizable="true" resize Dialog
            draggable="true" is default, dragg Dilaog
            -->


    <Dialog id="oDialogCreate" title="Create New Item" contentWidth="400px" resizable="true" class="myDialogStyle" >
    <content>
        <VBox alignItems="Center">
            <Label text="Name" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="nameInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput" />
            <Label text="Category" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="categoryInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput"/>
            <Label text="Supplier" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="supplierInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput"/>
            <Label text="Status" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="statusInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput"/>
            <Label text="DateOfProductionInput" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="dateOfProductionInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput"/>
            <Label text="Price" class="dialogLabel"/>
            <Input id="priceInput" width="100%" class="dialogInput"/>
        </VBox>
    </content>
    <beginButton>
        <Button text="Add" type="Accept" press="onAdd" class="dialogButton"/>
    </beginButton>
    <endButton>
        <Button text="Cancel" type="Reject" press="onCancel" class="dialogButton"/>
    </endButton>
</Dialog>

    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: your code snippets do not work